# How to dim the background when a confirm() is shown and turn dim off when user answers yes or no?

Tags: javascript

I found the similar question about using alert() but changing that to confirm() doesn't work.  Need to return the response.   This results in the "Not confirmed" alert being displayed first. What do I need to do to fix this?

```js
var originalConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function(args) {
  document.querySelector("html").classList.add("darkenPage");
  setTimeout(function() {
    var x = originalConfirm(args);
    document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("darkenPage");
    return (x);
  });
}
```

```css
html.darkenPage {
  background-color: black;
}

html.darkenPage body {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="if (confirm('Hello World, yes or no')) { alert('Confirmed'); } else { alert('Not confirmed'); }  ">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Your `confirm` always returns `undefined`. You return the response from the anonymous function that you pass `setTimeout` but not from the `confirm` function. I don't see any reason to have that `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` runs the callback asynchronously, that means the return value inside the callback is not actually used, and the `confirm` function will return before the timeout callback is called. You'd need to use another callback as argument to confirm in order to get the response, but that would change the original API.

```js
var originalConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function(args, callback) {
  document.querySelector("html").classList.add("darkenPage");
  setTimeout(function() {
    var x = originalConfirm(args);
    document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("darkenPage");
    callback(x);
  });
}
```

```css
html.darkenPage {
  background-color: black;
}

html.darkenPage body {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="confirm('Hello World, yes or no', function (confirmed) { alert(confirmed ? 'Confirmed' : 'Not confirmed'); })">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: I have read your explanation but I didn't get it could you help me to understand your code?